# How can I refer to a i18n entry in .json files ?

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization, sapui5

I am currently developing a UI with SAP UI5 and would like to internationalize all text in there.

This is part of my view in .xml format. Getting the text in the specific languages by using the placeholders in {} brackets works fine here.

```
<headerToolbar>
    <Toolbar>
        <Title text="{i18n>orderDetails}"/>
    </Toolbar>
</headerToolbar>
<columns>
    <Column>
        <Text text="{i18n>statisticsSubject}"/>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Text text="{i18n>statisticsNumber}"/>
    </Column>
</columns>
```

I also got a Tile Container in the view, which is getting it's contents from a .json file.

```
<TileContainer
    tiles="{/Tiles}"
    height="200pt">
    <StandardTile
        icon="{icon}"
        type="{type}"
        number="{number}"
        numberUnit="{numberUnit}"
        title="{title}"
        info="{info}"
        infoState="{infoState}"/>
</TileContainer>
```

This is the relevant part of the .json file:

```
  "Tiles":
  [
    {
      "title":"Anmelden",
      "icon":"sap-icon://inspect"
    },
    {
      "title":"Abmelden",
      "icon":"sap-icon://inspect-down"
    },
    {
      "title":"Liste",
      "icon":"sap-icon://activity-items"
    }
  ],
```

As the titles of the tiles are currently german only, I would also like to internationalize them by using i18n. When I change a title to a placeholder in {} brackets, I can just see the placeholder in the final UI-result but not the appropriate translation. Is there a possibility to use i18n in .json files or will I need to find a different solution for storing the data for the tiles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism for doing internationalization on JSON files with the JsonModel. But that does not mean that you cannot make one yourself. You can find an example here: https://github.com/serban-petrescu/serban-petrescu.github.io/blob/master/model/models.js#L53.

In a nutshell, you have to read the JSON first by using jQuery.ajax. After you receive the data, you can recurse it checking the following 3 cases:

- If it is a string and it matches your desired i18n marker pattern (e.g. `i18n>myTranslatableKey`) then you replace the string with a text from the i18n bundle.
- If it is an array, you iterate through its indexes and recursively call your function on each element.
- If it is an object, you iterate through its keys and recursively call your function on each member.

You can either make these changes in place (i.e. chaining the object that you received from the jQuery.ajax call) or you can create a copy of the object (like in the example above).

Another possibility (not that nice) would be to use a [factory function](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/335848ac1174435c901baaa55f6d7819.html) instead of binding the aggregation with a template from the XML. Inside the factory function, you will have to instantiate your tiles and you can do something along the lines:

```
buildTile: function(sId, oContext) {
  return new StandardTile({
    icon: "{icon}",
    type: "{type}",
    number: "{number}",
    numberUnit: "{numberUnit}",
    info: "{info}",
    infoState: "{infoState}",

    // if title is {i18n>someKey} it will bind the
    // title property against the i18n model
    title: oContext.getProperty("title")
  });
}
```